# jsPDF multiple errors when trying to implement

Tags: angular, jspdf

I have a project where we are incorporating jsPDF and autotable but I have hit a wall..

Commands I ran:

```
npm i jspdf --save  
npm install @types/jspdf --save
npm i jspdf jspdf-autotable --save
```

angular.json:

```
"scripts": ["../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",
              "../node_modules/jspdf-autotable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"]
```

ts file:

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';


const doc = new jsPDF('portrait','px','a4');
    doc.autotable({
      head: [['Equipment_ID', 'Equipment_type_Description', 'Equipment_Description', 'Infrastructure_Name','Section_Name','Equipment_Condition','Equipment_Cost','Is_Active','Actions']],
      body: this.dataSource
    })

    doc.save("EquipmentList");


  }
```

error

```
Property 'autotable' does not exist on type 'jsPDF'
```

when I declare it like this:

```
declare var jsPDF: any;
```

and I ng serve, I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Script file ../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js does not exist.
See "C:\Users\reube\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-4iWKp5\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Comment: try to import it like this : ```import jsPDF from 'jspdf';```
```import autoTable from 'jspdf-autotable';```

Comment: When I do that it gives me this error: This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work with jspdf-autotable in **angular 5**, one must install jspdf and jspdf-autotable via npm

```sh
    npm install jspdf --save
    npm install @types/jspdf --save-dev
    npm install jspdf-autotable --save
```

also, add the jspdf and jspdf-autotable files to the scripts array in (angular-cli.json or angular.json) depends on your angular version

```
    "scripts": [
    "node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",
    "node_modules/jspdf-autotable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"
    ],
```

and in component never import jspdf or jspdf-autotable just.

**Forget about the following import.**

```
    import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'; 
    import 'jspdf-autotable';
```

Just use Before @Component:

```
    declare var jsPDF: any;
```

Comment: So I re did it exactly like you did and get the following error: An unhandled exception occurred: Script file ../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js does not exist.. When I have a look in the jspdf node module there is no jspdf.min.js so I have no clue whats ggoing on

Comment: of course, because you have ```../``` before node_modules just copy the import from the answer

Comment: I removed the ```../``` from both and still same error. When I go to node modules and open jsPDF. I see that there is no jspdf.min.js file at all

Comment: so there is something wrong in the installation , remove these packages and try to re install

Comment: install the version just before the latest: 1.5.3

Comment: I'm still fairly new with angular, what would be the easiest way to remove and install the correct version? Thanks!

Comment: remove jspdf : ```npm uninstall jspdf --save``` 
then run ```npm install jspdf --save```

Comment: for a specific version do this: ```npm install jspdf@1.5.3 --save```

Comment: This worked! Thanks!. now just to figure out why my table body is empty lol

Answer (score 1):

Please try removing below  code form angular.json:

```
"scripts": ["../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",
           "../node_modules/jspdf-autotable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"]
```

Comment: Quickly tried it, the program serves but when the function is fired I get this in console: "ERROR ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined"

Comment: @Bike_dotnet remove `declare var jsPDF: any;` this line also

Comment: When I remove that import and use the type like I did in the OP, it does say that Property 'autotable' does not exist on type 'jsPDF'